# Loading NDIS drivers automatically on Windows Embedded CE 6.0 during boot time

Tags: driver, windows-ce, platform-builder

I have a Wi-Fi driver from a manufacturer. That driver has Plug and Play support. After the adapter has been inserted or removed, Windows CE has recognized it successfully. But at boot time, if the adapter is "inserted state", CE OS does not load it so I must remove then insert it.

I want to load the driver automatically during boot time. Is it possible?

Before, I've written a simple stream interface driver. I have edited project.reg to create a sub-key under HKLM\Devices\BuiltIn so that Device Manager can load automatically during boot time. And it was successfully loaded. But Wi-Fi driver is a non-stream driver. Can Device Manager load Wi-Fi driver automatically with the same way?

Are "all of drivers under HKLM\Drivers\BuiltIn" stream interface drivers? What differences are there between stream interface drivers and NDIS Wi-Fi drivers from the point of loading automatically during boot-time? I will very happy if you can explain it a little.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to load the driver automatically during boot time. Is it
>   possible?

Yes, it is definitely possible. That was the main purpose of plug and play devices. The WinCE device automatically loads a driver appropriate to the Plug 'n' Play device. There would not be any need for doing it manually. If so, then there is no need for a Plug 'n' Play functionality.

As this is not happening in your case, you could try the following

1. Have you checked with any other Plug-n-Play devices to the WinCE device?
2. Each time you plug-out and plug-in, is it installing the drivers or is it just loading? You can verify the debug logs to confirm this.

> Are "all of drivers under HKLM\Drivers\BuiltIn" stream interface drivers? What differences are there between stream interface drivers and NDIS Wi-Fi drivers from the point of loading automatically during boot-time?

Actually, the block devices can also be loaded automatically, as similar to stream interface drivers. The **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\BuiltIn** registry key recognizes built-in block devices also.

You can refer this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee482448.aspx) for further information regarding loading the block devices.